# CSS Sentence Case

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to format a "SENTENCE CASE"? e.g. "THIS IS SENTENCE 1. THIS IS SENTENCE 2. THIS IS SENTENCE 3.  change to -> This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.

Comment: Format your question properly so that we can get what you expect.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322314/convert-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase-and-first-uppercase-in-sentence-using-css

Comment: Are these sentences user input?  What if they contain names, acronyms, or other words that should be capitalized in mid-sentence?  It seems like any solution that blindly lower-cases everything but the first letter in each sentence will have problems in some situations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CSS can convert first letter of each word, but not first letter of each sentence.  Probably you need to use Javascript here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
<!--
function fixCapitalsText (text)
{
  result = "";

  sentenceStart = true;
  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
  {
    ch = text.charAt (i);

    if (sentenceStart && ch.match (/^\S$/))
    {
      ch = ch.toUpperCase ();
      sentenceStart = false;
    }
    else
    {
      ch = ch.toLowerCase ();
    }

    if (ch.match (/^[.!?]$/))
    {
      sentenceStart = true;
    }

    result += ch;
  }

  return result;
}

function fixCapitalsNode (node)
{
  if (node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4) // Text or CDATA
  {
    node.textContent = fixCapitalsText (node.textContent);
  }

  if (node.nodeType == 1)
    for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
      fixCapitalsNode (node.childNodes.item (i));
}
// -->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="fixCapitalsNode (document.body);">
    THIS IS FIRST SENTENCE.
    THIS IS SECOND SENTENCE.
    This Is Third Sentence.
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: hey it should be `var result = ""` not `result = ""`. Well, +1.

Comment: This is cool it works fine to me! Thanks..but your code is very long can we shortened it?

Comment: can I?.. THanks @Aspiring Aqib

Comment: @Newbie here is it : http://jsfiddle.net/cTXzg/2/ hahahahah :P

Comment: Cool! much better and cleaner. Thanks dude..

Oh BTW. what if all caps? can you update your code Aspiring Aqib?

Comment: @Newbie hey man sorry, I didn't got notif of this comment. So, can't reply you. But still use this: http://jsfiddle.net/cTXzg/3/

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib. I think the first one is good enough. But thanks also for the last one. It'll be a good reference for the future uses. +1 you deserve it. Thanks dude \m/ cool!

Comment: @Newbie which thing in fiddle 3 you did not liked ?

Comment: I actually like it buy.. I realized that since it was a comment, it shouldn't be properly cased just like facebook comments. :D. You did a nice job dude. cheers!

Answer (score 37):

you can use `id/class:first-letter` property to achieve that.

Taken from the duplicate question mentioned above:

```
p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: If you mean the `::first-letter` pseudo-element, that targets the first letter in an _element_

Comment: I also tried this one `::first-letter` but it won't capitalized the second sentence. It became like this. ** This is sentence 1. this is sentence 2 ** what I what is ** This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2 **

Comment: well, next possible solution is using another element for the first character of every sentense to have more control on it and then use `text-transoform:lowercase` for rest of contents as we really don't know what kind of element are being used. Say if it's in a list item you can apply `first-letter` pseudo element to every `li` element.

Comment: @Newbie you would need to wrap each sentence in a separate element as well. I recommend a `span`.

Comment: The caveat here is that it must be used on a block-level element. See this post ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/7631782/813187 ) for details.

Comment: This should generally be avoided, since some words should start lowercase even at the start of a sentence, e.g. "iOS".

Answer (score 14):

There are only three CSS properties.

```
text-transform: capitalize;
text-transform: lowercase;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

None of them is gonna output as you want. You can use lowercase text-transform and them use JavaScript to capitalize first word of each sentence.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cTXzg/2/)

Comment: Javascript cannot override text-transform, so you would need to use `text-transform:none`

Comment: @JanDvorak I wanted to say that use CSS lowercase text-transform. Then get innerHTML of that element and using JS to capitalize each word of sentence. Hold on! give an example. :D

Comment: When you apply Javascript, the text _stays_ CSS-transformed. You need to disable the transform after applying Javascript. Moreover, Javascript won't see the effects of that transformation.

Comment: @JanDvorak just realize that. using JS `.toLowerCase()` method.

Comment: What is that question?

Comment: @JanDvorak http://jsfiddle.net/cTXzg/1/ see this how can i remove all spaces before any character in string ? because innerHTML also including the 3 white spaces of first sentence.Hence, not capitalizing first letter. It can be done quite easily by RegEx. But I am not good at it.

Comment: Look into `.trim()` ... but I was hoping for something shorter

Comment: @JanDvorak It will replace all spaces in the sentence. I knew but was not using due to that.

Comment: Not all of them. Just the leading space and the trailing space.

Comment: yeah ? really man thanks but i think somebody has better code than me down there :D

Answer (score -5):

You could use css `text-transform:capitalize;` property

Comment: that would capitalize all first letters

Comment: `capitalize` capitalises all words

Comment: `text-transform: capitalize;` makes every word capitalize. What I want is every **first letter in a sentence** become capitalize just like my example.

Comment: Also, capitalize only modifies the first letter of each word, not later letters.  So if other letters in the word are capitalized to start with, they will stay capitalized.