# Capitalize first letter of various tags content element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to capitalize the first letter of various html elements such as p, h2, h3, h4.

[This stack question has helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931117/css-sentence-case), however, it only targets the p tag. How can I say to target more than one tag?

Such as:

```
function change(charm) {
   var string = eval(charm).toLowerCase(), change = "", newstring = string.split("."),   tochange;
   for (var i = 0; i < newstring.length; i++) {
       tochange = newstring[i].trim().charAt(0);
       newstring[i] = newstring[i].replace(tochange, tochange.toUpperCase());
}
   change = newstring.join(" . ");
   return change;
}

var text = change("document.getElementsByTagName('p, h2, h3, h4')[0].innerHTML");
document.getElementsByTagName("p, h2, h3, h4")[0].innerHTML = text;
```

That doesn't work, am I doing something wrong with targetting various elements?

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) won't accept a comma-separated list... it expectes either one tag name or an asterisk.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought by the result. Any other way I can achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Multiple calls or [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: No, you don't. There's no good reason to do this at all.

Comment: Capitalize the first letter of the content of the tag, or the tag name itself? If you're talking about the tag name itself, there's no reason to do that, unless you're outputting it somewhere and need to make it look pretty.

Comment: it's "the first letter of the content of the tag"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CSS only approach:

```
p:first-letter,
h1:first-letter,
h2:first-letter,
h3:first-letter,
h4:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[:first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) is ie9+

Comment: first-letter? What's that?

Comment: @rob.m added a link to MDN

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) won't accept a comma-separated list... it expectes either one tag name or an asterisk.

Try [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead.

Comment: Bah, I didn't notice the [css] tag... was focused on the chunk of javascript in the post.