# Capitalizing first letter of each word in a sentence full of uppercase characters

Tags: css

I have a page with several uppercase strings that I want to transform in capatalized strings. I need to **capitalize the first letter of each word**.

If I use:

```
text-transform: lowercase;
text-transform: capitalize;
```

This doesn't work because only the second rule is applied. Is there any workaround for this?
I prefer not to use JS.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? All in lower case except the first letter of the first word?

Comment: You could do that using this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322335/3834042

Comment: I need to uppercase the first letter of each word. thanks

Comment: @user3174311: I have updated the question and title based on your comment. Please feel free to roll back/edit if you feel it is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think achieving this is possible with only CSS. You may have to use JavaScript (or) convert the uppercase string to all lowercase characters at the source (if you are dynamically populating the content at server side).

Comment: Here is another question on similar lines - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471157/css-text-transform-capitalize-on-all-caps?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS code:

```
p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
p:first-letter 
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: This will capitalize only the first letter mate. I think you may have missed OP's clarification in comments.