# Text Input To Sentence Case

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form whose is saved to the database and generates a PDF.

I want to have the input text transformed to sentence case. Tried `style="text-transform:capitalize"` but it still save the input as it was typed into the database.  How can I do this, perhaps with JavaScript?

```
<form class="form-style-9" name="litterregistration" id="LitterReg" method="post">

<li>
                        <input type="text" name="AKennel" required class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Kennel Name" style="text-transform:capitalize" />
                        <input type="text" name="BDamMother" required class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Dame (Mother)" style="text-transform:capitalize"/>
</li>

  <input type="submit" value="Save as PDF" onClick="Onsubmit1();"  />
  <input type="button" onclick="ClearFormFields()" value="Clear All Fields">
</form

<script>
function Onsubmit1()
{
   document.litterregistration.action = "tcpdf/examples/form-litter-regis.php"

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Uppercase Letter to Lowercase and First Uppercase in Sentence using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322314/convert-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase-and-first-uppercase-in-sentence-using-css)

Comment: Move the submit listener off the button and onto the form. Forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button. Dunno what *ClearFormFields* does, but likely a reset button will do the job with zero script support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please, note this is a NOT scalabe solution, and will only work with this specif code**

Hi, a few notes first:
- you call a `ClearFormFields()` function but it isn't build anywhere;
- the name `onSubmit1()` for the function is not really good.
- You've missed a `/>` in the form tag.

With this is mind, this should do the (THIS) trick:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySubmitAction(myAction) {
    with (document.getElementById("LitterReg")) {
        AKennel.value = AKennel.value.toUpperCase();
        BDamMother.value = BDamMother.value.toUpperCase();
    }

    document.litterregistration.action = myAction;

    return true;
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-style-9" name="litterregistration" id="LitterReg" method="post">
<li>
    <input type="text" name="AKennel" required class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Kennel Name" style="text-transform:capitalize" />
    <input type="text" name="BDamMother" required class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Dame (Mother)" style="text-transform:capitalize"/>
</li>

  <input type="submit" value="Save as PDF" onclick="mySubmitAction('tcpdf/examples/form-litter-regis.php');" />
  <input type="button" onclick="ClearFormFields()" value="Clear all fields" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thx a million man!!! Just to clarify, I didnt paste all the code The ClearFormFields() is beneath the onsubmit function - dint think it was necessary to include it.  If I may asked, is it possible to transform it to Sentence Case instead of uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $input1 = $( '#input-1' );

$.toSentenceCase = function ( value ) {
  var val = value.split( ' ' );
  
  for ( var i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    val[i] = val[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val[i].substr(1);
  }
  
  return val.join( ' ' );
}

$input1.on( 'blur', function ( e ) {
  var $this = $( this );
  
  $this.val( $.toSentenceCase( $this.val() ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input-1">
</form>
```