# Replace first letter of sentence in HTML tags with capital letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

This isn't something that can be solved with a CSS structural pseudo-class due to the nature of the text. Not all the sentences start inside a new `<p>` or any tag for that matter. I'm after something that will also capitalise text after certain symbols or tags as well such as `.` and `<br/>`. For most reading the question in full have already noted this but I've been requested to add this explanation to the top of my question for the few that are suggesting this has already been answered on stack overflow in the form of CSS structural pseudo-class i.e. `p::first-letter`

An example string would be

```
<h3 class="media-heading">description</h3>
    <p>there is a john entrance hall with staircase, beautiful lounge with stone fireplace and wood-burner, exposed at stone walls and beams. kitchen/ dining room, is huge room with fitted kitchen, wood burner and dining area with doors to the terrace.&nbsp; upstairs there are 3 double bedrooms, the master with en-suite bathroom, family shower room and a landing.there is a self contained apartment, with private terrace, (which could be incorporated into the house,) which has a lounge, bedroom, kitchen and shower room.the cottage/gite has an entrance hall, lounge with fireplace, fitted kitchen, 4 bedrooms, bathroom and shower room. outside there is a&nbsp; private garden and solar shower.&nbsp; rental is very popular in the summer in this region and this gite could be rented out for over £1000 per week.<br _moz_dirty="true"></p><p>paragraph break<br>line break</p>
```

Wanted Output

```
<h3 class="media-heading">Description</h3>
    <p>There is a john entrance hall with staircase, beautiful lounge with stone fireplace and wood-burner, exposed at stone walls and beams. Kitchen/ dining room, is huge room with fitted kitchen, wood burner and dining area with doors to the terrace. Upstairs there are 3 double bedrooms, the master with en-suite bathroom, family shower room and a landing. There is a self contained apartment, with private terrace, (which could be incorporated into the house,) which has a lounge, bedroom, kitchen and shower room. The cottage/gite has an entrance hall, lounge with fireplace, fitted kitchen, 4 bedrooms, bathroom and shower room. Outside there is a private garden and solar shower. Rental is very popular in the summer in this region and this gite could be rented out for over £1000 per week.<br _moz_dirty="true"></p><p>Paragraph break<br>line break</p>
```

What I'm after doing is getting the first letter after a HTML tag capitalised and also after the `.`. Humanising the text basically. I've found a number of great string humanising http://stringjs.com is a perfect example but it doesn't work for the example string above. I'm guessing due to the `<` being the first character.

Any help would be appreciated. Stripping HTML out isn't an option really unless I can replace the text with the formatted string.

Comment: You (probably) don't need to use JavaScript for this; in most cases you can simply use CSS: `:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }`? [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).

Comment: @DavidThomas Can `k` at `. kitchen/ ` be matched at `css`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Uppercase Letter to Lowercase and First Uppercase in Sentence using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322314/convert-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase-and-first-uppercase-in-sentence-using-css)

Comment: @War10ck Would any of the approaches at linked Question match `k` at `. kitchen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.html(function)`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/((^|\.)|(\.(?:\s+|&nbsp;(?:\s+))|<br>))[a-z]/g` to match first `a-z` character at beginning of string or `.` followed by `a-z` or `.` followed by `a-z`, or `.` followed by `&nbsp;` followed by space `a-z` or `a-z`, or `<br>` followed by `a-z`; `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.indexOf()` to handle non-breaking space character `&nbsp;`, `String.prototype.toUpperCase()`

```js
var re = /((^|\.)|(\.(?:\s+|&nbsp;(?:\s+))|<br>))[a-z]/g;

$("h3, p").html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(re, function(match) {
    var space = "&nbsp;";
    return match.indexOf(space) > -1 
           ? match.slice(0, match.indexOf(";")) 
             + match.slice(match.indexOf(";") + 1).toUpperCase()
           : match.toUpperCase();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="media-heading">description</h3>
    <p>there is a john entrance hall with staircase, beautiful lounge with stone fireplace and wood-burner, exposed at stone walls and beams. kitchen/ dining room, is huge room with fitted kitchen, wood burner and dining area with doors to the terrace.&nbsp; upstairs there are 3 double bedrooms, the master with en-suite bathroom, family shower room and a landing.there is a self contained apartment, with private terrace, (which could be incorporated into the house,) which has a lounge, bedroom, kitchen and shower room.the cottage/gite has an entrance hall, lounge with fireplace, fitted kitchen, 4 bedrooms, bathroom and shower room. outside there is a&nbsp; private garden and solar shower.&nbsp; rental is very popular in the summer in this region and this gite could be rented out for over £1000 per week.<br _moz_dirty="true"></p><p>paragraph break<br>line break</p>
```

Comment: Is the markup editor stripping out the line break or is the code above?

Comment: @War10ck The code. See updated post; substituted `.html()` for `.text()`

Comment: @War10ck See updated post. Included logic to handle `&nbsp;`

Comment: This is perfect! I've searched so much for something like this. Is there anyway to get the letter after a `<br/>` `<br>` `<br _moz_dirty="true">` as well?

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon See updated post. Included `|<br>` at close of first capture group

Comment: You are a god send. I need to get into my regex a lot more than I am clearly. Such a powerful tool. Thank you again

Comment: The `&nbsp;` part looks wrong. Have you tested this case? I believe HTML converts this to a non-ASCII character, so the string `html` should contain the actual character, not the HTML code. So the regex should contain the character too, or an appropriate (i.e. backslash-escaped) version of it. (However, if the script is embedded in the HTML, which I wouldn't recommend, then it would still work, _if_ the javascript parser runs on the HTML-escaped string.)

Comment: @DavidKnipe Not certain what you mean? Tested at stacksnippets. Can you create a plnkr plnkr.co to demonstrate the test case which you are describing?

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon See updated post. Previous `RegExp` did not match `".t"` at `"landing.there"`

Answer (score -2):

You can use bacis CSS styles
Capitalize First letter of the Words

```
 p {
        text-transform:capitalize;
    }
```

Comment: The last part of your answer is incorrect. `initial` does ***not*** capitalize the first letter of the sentence. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) for more details.

Comment: Confused with this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-transform&preval=initial

Comment: Look at the differences between the values of `none` and `initial`. There aren't any because `initial` simply means the initial value that would be applied to the element with the out-of-the-box stylesheet applied by the browser. In this case `text-transform`'s initial state is `none`.

Comment: @Vijai Does approach match `k` at `. kitchen`?

Comment: Scratches the surface of the problem unfortunately.